# NX workspace angular - generate component in library

Tags: angular, nomachine-nx

I don't know how to generate component to library in nx workspace. Here is my library structure. Libraries are in folders (for example libs/features, libs/shared). I would like to create component in library orders (libs/features/orders).

`nx g @nrwl/angular:component orders-list --project orders`

Error:

> Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.

**angular.json**
`{ "version": 2, "projects": { "orders": "libs/features/orders" } }`

How to generate component to library, if module is in subfolder?

Answer (score 2):

Use `features-orders` for the project.

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:library orders --directory=features 
nx g @nrwl/angular:component orders-list --project=features-orders
```

Output

```
>  NX  Generating @nrwl/angular:library

CREATE libs/features/orders/README.md
CREATE libs/features/orders/tsconfig.lib.json
CREATE libs/features/orders/tsconfig.spec.json
CREATE libs/features/orders/src/index.ts
CREATE libs/features/orders/src/lib/features-orders.module.ts
CREATE libs/features/orders/project.json
CREATE libs/features/orders/tsconfig.json
UPDATE tsconfig.base.json
CREATE libs/features/orders/jest.config.ts
CREATE libs/features/orders/src/test-setup.ts
CREATE libs/features/orders/.eslintrc.json

>  NX  Generating @nrwl/angular:component

CREATE libs/features/orders/src/lib/orders-list/orders-list.component.html
CREATE libs/features/orders/src/lib/orders-list/orders-list.component.spec.ts
CREATE libs/features/orders/src/lib/orders-list/orders-list.component.ts
CREATE libs/features/orders/src/lib/orders-list/orders-list.component.scss
UPDATE libs/features/orders/src/lib/features-orders.module.ts
```